# Is there an tutorial for how to set up an ldap server and after to connect it with a simple laravel app?

Tags: laravel, ldap

I set up the ldap using DigitalOcean tutorial and installed AdLdap2 package and if anybody can clarify to me why on login to the ldap server still try to login with default username and password, i can't explain properly the problem if it doesn't make sense to you, can you just put here some links which helped you to set up the server and connect a laravel project with ldap

Comment: There is a [plugin/module](https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2-Laravel) available, tested and works great

Comment: apparently i can't really set it up, and it always login me up with the default admin / password credentials even if i login via laravel default auth, i did almost every step of this package setting up, i guess i miss something, or i set up the server wrong (

Comment: You have to change the config file to match LDAP settings, then change the `LoginController` by overriding the `attemptLogin` method to return either true or false if the credentials provided are okay and that should be it

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm a little late but these are my notes from when I set it up for one of my apps.

## Adldap2-Laravel (NoDatabaseProvider)

### Installation

Install the Adldap2-laravel package:

> $ composer require adldap2/adldap2-laravel

Create the auth scaffolding:

> $ php artisan make:auth

### Configuration

Define the following environment variables in your *.env* file:

```php
# .env

LDAP_HOSTS=[192.168.1.10]
LDAP_PORT=[389]
LDAP_BASE_DN=[DC=contoso,DC=com]
LDAP_USERNAME=[ldap@contoso.com]
LDAP_PASSWORD=[password123]
```

Disable the default routes if only using LDAP authentication. In your */routes/web.php* file, make the following changes for `Auth::routes()` :

```php
# /routes/web.php

Auth::routes([
  'reset'    => false,
  'verify'   => false,
  'register' => false,
])
```

In your */resources/views/auth/login.blade.php* file, change the label for email address to **Username**, remove the `@error('email)` section from the corresponding text input and change the name on that text input to whatever LDAP attribute you are looking users up by (`samaccountname` or `userprincipalname`) Finished text input should look something similar to this:

```php
# /resources/views/auth/login.blade.php

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="samaccountname" value="{{ old('samaccountname') }}" required autofocus>
```

Create the *ldap.php* and *ldap_auth.php* file by running the following two commands:

> $ php artisan vendor:publish --provider "Adldap\Laravel\AdldapServiceProvider"
>
> $ php artisan vendor:publish --provider "Adldap\Laravel\AdldapAuthServiceProvider"

Change the user driver to use ldap instead of eloquent under `providers` in */config/auth.php* and comment out the model below it, like so:

```php
# /config/auth.php

  'providers' => [
      'users' => [
          'driver' => 'ldap', // <- was eloquent, changed to ldap
          # 'model'  => App\User::class, // <- commented out, not using anymore
```

In */config/ldap_auth.php*:

- Change the `provider` from `DatabaseUserProvider` to `NoDatabaseUserProvider`:

```php
# /config/ldap_auth.php

  'provider' => Adldap\Laravel\Auth\NoDatabaseProvider::class
```

- Change the `locate_users_by` under `ldap` to whatever field you plan to authenticate users by (`samaccountname` or `userprincipalname`)

```php
# /config/ldap_auth.php

  'ldap' => [
    'locate_users_by' => 'samaccountname',
    'bind_users_by'   => 'distinguishedname',
  ],
```

In your */app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php* file, you must add a `username()` function that returns the LDAP attribute you are authenticating users by:

```php
# /app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php

  public function username()
  {
    return 'samaccountname';
  }
```

In your */config/app.php* file, it's helpful to add the alias for the Adldap Facade to keep from having to type it out every time you need to access it:

```php
# /config/app.php

  'aliases' => [

    'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
    'Arr' => Illuminate\Support\Arr::class,
    . // scroll
    . // to
    . // the
    . // bottom
    'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
    'Adldap' => Adldap\Laravel\Facades\Adldap::class // <- add this

  ],
```

### Usage

- After successfully authenticating, if you add `use Auth;` in your controller with the other *use* contracts in the beginning of the file, you can access the authenticated user's attributes like so:

```php
# /app/Http/Controllers/HomeController

use Auth;

public function index()
{
  $user = Auth::user();
  $cn = $user->getCommonName(); // assigns currently authenticated user's Common Name
  return view('home')->with('cn', $cn);
  // using {{ $cn }} on the home's view would output the Common Name
}
```

- If you want to query the LDAP server for all other users, you can add `use Adldap;` with the other *use* contracts and use the query builder:

```php
# /app/Http/Controllers/HomeController

use Adldap;

public function index()
{
  $users = Adldap::search()->where('objectclass', '=', 'person')->sortBy('cn', 'asc')->get();
  return view('home', compact('users'))
  // use a foreach loop on the view to iterate through users and attributes
}
```

Comment: I don't why didn't anybody give this answer an upvote. It was really a tough job for any newbie (at least for me). Now I regret why I didn't start following this tutorial when I first find this answer. I have spent the whole day trying to connect my Laravel application with my OpenLDAP server and when I finished my task, I came here to cross check my work which was excatly the same (except the `identifiers` settings). Still, thanks for such a nice explanation.